# Is it portable to do "export VAR=value" in shell scripts?

Tags: shell, unix, posix

I see a lot of snippets that do:

```
SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=whatever_value
export SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME
```

And I was wondering why people don't just do:

```
export SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=whatever_value
```

My questions:

1. Is a POSIX-conforming shell required to support the `export VAR=value` syntax? I.e., is it portable?
2. If so, why isn't this shorter syntax prevalent?

Comment: I know I've seen question this before, but can't find the duplicate. Maybe it was on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Short answer: POSIX requires support for `export var=value`, but it was not part of the original Bourne shell. Doing the assignment and export in two steps is the old-fashioned way. Try not to be shocked, but a few computers with non-POSIX-compliant `/bin/sh` might still be running, and more than a few people who learned in the pre-POSIX days are still programming.

Comment: I think @Wumpus's comment is sufficient as an answer.

Comment: Before we agree it's a sufficient answer, can you give me an example for a shell "in production" that does **not** support the `export var=value` syntax? I just want to make sure kittens will indeed die if I use this syntax.

Comment: Since nobody identified a duplicate yet, I've upgraded my comment to an answer

Comment: @NiccoloM., "in production" meaning in the last how many years? Solaris shipped a noncompliant `/bin/sh` well into modern times (more than 15 years after POSIX.2 was published). Granted, they *also* put a POSIX-compliant implementation elsewhere on the system, I think under `/usr/xpg/bin` or somesuch, but that didn't help scripts with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang.

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed in this industry. Test your script with the shell having minimal capabilities. As far as I know, it is `dash` nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is it portable" is not quite the same question as "is it POSIX". `export var=value` is specified by POSIX, but it is not portable if you target the wider group of all (current and legacy) Bourne-like shells.

I don't know if there are any systems currently being sold by a vendor that don't allow this syntax. But again, "systems currently being sold" and "systems currently running" are different questions. We'd need some actual users of AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, etc. to stop by and tell us...

You may find a script using the two-step "assign then export" for any of these reasons:

1. The script was written a long time ago and has been in maintenance mode since then. Combining the statements would be a purely cosmetic change, which is undesirable.
2. The script is actually intended to run on some legacy system with a non-POSIX `/bin/sh`
3. The author learned shell programming a long time ago and just does things out of habit, knowing that the old ways (when not contradicted by POSIX) are at least as portable as POSIX. This type of person may also be seen using `expr` for arithmetic, and the mystical construction `${1+"$@"}` may appear.
4. (the worst case) The author copied bits and pieces of other scripts without understanding them, and this piece came from a script in one of the previous categories.

Comment: Sun shipped a pre-POSIX /bin/sh well into the mid-2000s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the meantime (see my answer) I've discovered yet another hole in the portability illusion :-(

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, [POSIX requires](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export) support of the syntax:

```
export name[=word]...
```

Certainly a non POSIX shell might fail on this syntax, but that is beyond the
scope of this question. The above syntax is portable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but I want to mention the following issue I've just discovered.

The following snippet behaves differently in bash than in dash:

```
names="one two three"
export BOBO=$names
```

1. In bash, variable BOBO will contain "one two three", as expected.
2. In dash, variable BOBO will contain "one". In other words: in dash, "export" is like a system command (like `ls`, `echo`, ...) in the sense that variable expansion gets carried out before the command sees it. The command, in dash, is effectively `export BOBO=one two three`.

(To make dash behave like bash we need to write `"$names"` instead, in quotes. Or not to use the `export var=val syntax` in the first place.)

**The same issue exists with `local var=$val`** (which isn't in POSIX, btw): you need to wrap `$val` in quotes if you want dash to handle it as expected.

**Considering that `/bin/sh` in popular systems (like Ubuntu) is actually dash, this is a humongous issue. (I wonder why I haven't heard of it!)**

EDIT:

I see that this issue is discussed in ["Are quotes needed for local variable assignment?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97560/are-quotes-needed-for-local-variable-assignment).

Comment: Well, this is only a problem if you have a habit of leaving your variable expansions unquoted, which is generally bad. The quoted form should be seen as the plain form, and the unquoted form should be seen as special.

Comment: @Wumpus: My habit it to always use quotes, except in the case of `var1=$var2`. I believe (believed?) that people who use quotes there are just ignorant of sh's syntax. Do you think I should change my habit? Can you demonstrate a case where `var1=$var2-$var3-$var4` can ever fail?

Comment: When you put an "export" in front of it, apparently. But in my opinion, doing `var=$foo` or `var=$(foo)` instead of `var="$foo"` or `var="$(foo)"` is not bad because it can fail, it's bad because it's taking advantage of a special case that isn't really necessary. You're showing off that you know assignment doesn't need quotes. It's excessive cleverness.